# Mocking NetworkStream with MemoryStream for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, stream

I have a class that is wrapping a stream, with the intention of that stream likely being a NetworkStream.  However in unit testing it is much easier to use a MemoryStream to verify functionality.  However I have noticed that MemoryStream and NetworkStream don't actually act the same on write.

When I write to a MemoryStream the seek pointer of the stream is set to the end of what I wrote.  In order to read out what I wrote I have to adjust the Seek pointer back to the beginning of what I wrote.

When I write to a NetworkStream the other end of the stream can read that data without adjusting the seek pointer.

I assume that a NetworkStream is handling the concept of the seek pointer internally and making sure that even though it is filling data into the stream on the other side it is not adjusting the pointer.

My question then is, what is the best way to mock that same behavior in the MemoryStream?  I thought I might just seek the pointer back the same number of bytes I write but that seems cludgy.  Also If I stack several of these streams together or other wrapped streams, how will they know whether the pointer needs reset or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MemoryStream isn't designed for how you are using it. A NetworkStream is designed to allow you to fill up a block of memory with your output. It is not designed to have a second object reading from what the original object is writing.

I would suggest that you create a FakeNetworkStream class. You would have two objects, writing to one would add data to the other. But the advantage of a FakeNetworkStream is that you can implement pathological socket behavior to detect as many bugs as possible.

1. Don't send any data until the user flushes the stream. Subtle bugs can arise when a socket is not flushed because where or not the data is actually sent can vary. By always waiting until the flush you can have your tests fail when a flush actually need to happen.
2. Read isn't guaranteed to produce all of the data you request. Simulate this by only ever producing a single byte at a time.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I thought things weren't making much sense the way they were.  And I hadn't thought about the potential shinangins that network streams would bring to the table, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

https://github.com/billpg/POP3Listener/commit/a73a325f21a955edd9f1023a94c586aba29cfadc#diff-80d1609ed97fdaa9538dea7547301577cc19b6f4466a1a0a3a0ac08ad3eea23e

This function returns two NetworkStream objects, a client and a server, by briefly opening a server, connecting to that server, and returning both ends.